# ¿ Como puedo devolver el certificado con el mayor año de una función constructora?

Tags: javascript

Escribe una función que retorne el ultimo certificado de un profesor (anio mas alto)
ej, si la persona tuviera estos certificados:
{
certificados: [{
nombre: 'Ingenieria',
anio: 2004,
entidad: 'UNT',
}, {
nombre: 'Master en Datos',
anio: 2012,
entidad: 'UBA'
}]
}
persona.getUltimoCertificado() // retorna { nombre: 'Master en Datos', anio: 2012', entidad: 'UBA'};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo ordenando tu array con base en la key "anio" con [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Una vez ordenado el array tomas el primer índice [0].

Recuerda que para ordenar de forma ascendente tienes que restar `a` de `b` y de forma descendente `b` de `a`, que es justamente lo que tú estás buscando.

```js
let certificados = {
    certificados: [
        { nombre: 'Ingenieria', anio: 2001, entidad: 'UNT', },
        { nombre: 'Master en Datos', anio: 2012, entidad: 'UBA' }
    ],
    getUltimoCertificado() {
        return this.certificados.sort((a, b) => b.anio - a.anio)[0]
    }
}

// retorna { nombre: 'Master en Datos', anio: 2012', entidad:'UBA'}
console.log(certificados.getUltimoCertificado())
```

Comment: gracias te agradezco muchisimo